# Simple IR gate switch

Tags: led, infrared, photodiode

Regards to all

I'm totally new with electronic and I need help with some schematics.

I find one circuit that fits my needs: simply instantly turn on the LEDs with press of a switch and dims them on release. Now I want to use IR photogate instead of a switch but when I combine another web based circuit of a IR photogate in Circuit Wizard software, dimming effect from first circuit is lost.

Am I on a right track and what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: trigger a monostable to increase pulse time on.

Comment: Way too broad. Feel free to ask a question on one specific topic, not an entire circuit design.

Comment: I find this circuit on web and just want to make it work for my needs.
I need help to improve that circuit, what is the easiest way to make UV LED lighten a bit longer.
Mr. JIm Dearden suggested 555 timer but that is way to advanced for a first time electronic enthusiast.
I was hoping that I will manage to do what I need only by adding some capacitors or something that simple but If trigger a monostable is the easiest and best way then I will google it to learn how.
Just need a good guidance to know in which direction I should go.